# Test selected target with preprocessors macro

Tags: ios, xcode, macros, preprocessor

I want to test the selected Target with preprocessors macro. Anybody have an idea ?

```
#if TARGET1
    #myVar @"aValue"
#elsif TARGET2
    #myVar @"anotherValue"
#endif
```

Thank you by advance !

Comment: Just add `TARGET1=1` to the target1 `Preprocessor Macros` and the same for target2 where it should be `TARGET2=1`. And use `#ifdef` and not `#if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See please 'Build Settings' tab in xcode project for a specific target and 'Preprocessor macros' option. You can define a macros there and use it in code like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #myVar @"aValue"
#else
    #myVar @"anotherValue"
#endif
```

[image]